# AngularJS date confusion with | date: 'short' not giving the correct date

Tags: angularjs

I have a table on my page with the following:

```
<td class="spotted-border">{{ row.modifiedDate | date:'short' }}</td>
<td class="spotted-border">{{ row.modifiedDate }}</td>
```

When I open a modal, modify the contents, post the data and replace the existing data in the row I find that the second of the dates is set correctly but the first date / time is often not correct. Below is the output for changes made at 10:22pm and 10:27pm.

```
7/9/13 11:02 PM    2013-07-09T22:22:22.2425232+08:00

7/10/13 12:19 AM   2013-07-09T22:27:55.6705942+08:00
```

It seems date:'short' is not really working as expected. When I use the Chrome debug I see the correct date is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EcmaScprit specifications do not allow for that high of precision in Date values and you are seeing this result when you are applying the 'short' date filter.

Anything over order of 3 precision (webkit does 5) and you will run into this issue.

```
<div ng-app ng-init="modifiedDate = '2013-07-09T22:22:22.2425232+08:00'">
    <input type="text" ng-model="modifiedDate"/>

    <h1>{{ modifiedDate | date:'short' }}</h1>

    <h1>{{ modifiedDate }}</h1>
</div>
```

**[Example showing the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/KHEqm/)**

If you truncate to 5 your date shows displays correctly.

> 2013-07-09T22:22:22.24252+08:00

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/KHEqm/1/)**

[More information from google group](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1525)

Comment: Mark - Thanks very much. My date comes from C# question.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;  I think probably many other people will run into this very same problem so hopefully the problem can be documented. I will look into how I can fix the problem on the server. It's a shame the issue was closed on the AngularJS side with no mention of putting a note in the documentation.